# Jquery: How to set fixed footer when scroll

Tags: jquery, css

lets show this site :-

http://mhageer.com

However, when we scroll the page... the footer goes away ands reappear when scrolling stops.. Is there a way we could just make it fixed on the screen an show all the time you are scrolling ?

How can i do that.

thankx

Comment: Plwase post your code have tried.

Comment: when scroll up i need to hide footer and when scroll down i need to show footer with fixed position

Answer (score 1):

Try this Example can help you.user `bottom:0px;` to place footer at bottom of page.

**HTML**

```
<div class="footer">Test Footer</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.footer{
    position:fixed;
    padding-bottom:-10px;
     bottom:0px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9WJGB/1/)

**JQUERY Edit-1**

```
 $(function(){
          //Keep track of last scroll
          var lastScroll = 0;
          $(window).scroll(function(event){
              //Sets the current scroll position
              var st = $(this).scrollTop();

              //Determines up-or-down scrolling
              if (st > lastScroll){
                $(".footer").css("display",'inline')
              } 
              if(st == 0){
                $(".footer").css("display",'none')
              }
              //Updates scroll position
              lastScroll = st;
          });
        });
```

when page will load, footer hide itself and when you scolldown it will show at bottom till scroll top.
[Demo](http://jsbin.com/UDameHuj/1/)

Comment: its show me footer fixed it i need hide it when open my site and when scroll down i need to show it

Comment: Check my answer i have updated it for when you scroll down it will show.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
footer{
   position:fixed;
   left:0;bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[see here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fixed-footer/).

use this css:

```
#footer {
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   height:30px;
   width:100%;
   background:#999;
}

/* IE 6 */
* html #footer {
   position:absolute;
   top:expression((0-(footer.offsetHeight)+(document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight)+(ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop))+'px');
}
```

and assign you footer div id of footer.

Comment: its show me footer fixed it i need hide it when open my site and when scroll down i need to show it

Answer (score 0):

you cant disable this div with css because it control with jquery i check your code you must disable this part of code but i cant say you how delete it your code gziped
better you change `#infinite-footer` id to `#infinite-footer1` and set this code in css:

```
#infinite-footer1 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border-top: 10px solid #D0D0D0;
    z-index: 9999;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

**Assume your footer**

```
<div id="footer">

</div>
```

OR

```
<table>
   <tr id="footer">
      <td>

      </td>
   <tr>
</table>
```

**You Can Use CSS like ----**

```
#footer
  {
  position:fixed; /* position:fixed will make the div or table row fixed */
  bottom:0px; /* This defines the position */
  left:0px; /* This also defines the position */
  z-index:199;
  width:100%;
  height:100px; /* You can change the height as you want */
  }
```

**Some BROWSERS do not support css at all but are familiar with JavaScript You can use ----**

```
<script language="javascript">

    function fixedFooter()
    {
    if (document.all) Offset=document.body.scrollTop; 
    else Offset=window.pageYOffset;
    document.getElementById('footer').style.top=Offset+'px';
    }

    setInterval('fixedFooter()',100);

</script>
```

**If you want that is must be visible when Scrolled Down**

*Remember that this is JQuery*

```
<script language="javascript">

$(document).scroll(function () 
  {
  var position = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (position > 800) 
     {
     $('.footer').fadeIn();
     } 
  else 
     {
     $('.footer').fadeOut();
     }
  });    

</script>
```

Comment: so when scroll up i need to hide footer and when scroll down i need to show footer with fixed position